# .htaccess and internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess

Have an .htaccess file  that  allows certain IPS and is supposed to allows any CSS requests through. This works perfectly in every browser except IE. None of the CSS is loaded

I have tried putting an .htaccess file that says "allow everything" inside the CSS folder still no luck.

In my research have seen some vague references to exploder has problem with the mime type but no more. Anyone encountered this before?

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css

<Files ~ "\.(css)$">
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Files>

<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 
allow from
allow from 
allow from  
allow from 
allow from 
</Limit>
```

Comment: Do you need `AddType application/x-httpd-php .css` for any specific reason?  My first thought would be that Apache is sending the wrong content-type in the response header, and IE is blowing up because of it. Can you verify that the response header contains the correct content-type?

Answer (score 0):

GET xyz/css/blake-secure-normal.css
200 OK (text/html)

Looks like it thinks it HTML not Will look at that.